# I want to reinstall eclipse due to complications, how do I do this, will it keep my work safe?

Tags: java, eclipse

I really need to re-install it since I can't open it all of a sudden. How do I do this without deleting any work that I've done? The problem is that eclipse "failed to lodd JNI shard library" etc etc.

Comment: Eclipse should leave your working directory(ies) alone.

Comment: When I use Eclipse, all my work is in the workspace folder I've set up, plus other folders where I keep project sources and data separately.  I'd definitely make a backup copy of the workspace.

Comment: You might save yourself a lot of time by reviewing the answers to the possible duplicate I linked before you go through the reinstallation process.

Comment: I actually think the problem is that I have a 32-bit, since I wanted to try something out I installed a 64-bit JRE recently, so should I just delete my eclipse file and then install it again as 64-bit without any harm being done? Thanks for you help!

Comment: Sound like a good opportunity to learn version control.

Comment: If you are using Eclipse 32-bit and JDK 64-bit; Eclipse won't work.
Both must be of the same architecture (either 32-bit or 64-bit).

Comment: In regards to your worries about your work; Eclipse keeps all projects as workspace(s). If you decided to change Eclipse to 64-bit, just make sure to open the same workspace again.

Answer (score 1):

Did you update your JRE/JDK recently? Check that you have JAVA_HOME points to a working Java installation. You might need to reinstall your Java, or even point your Eclipse to new JDK by modifying `eclipse.ini` file. Reinstalling Eclipse will probably accomplish nothing. 
Other than that, as long as you don't delete your workspace directory, your work should be safe.